# What is the best practice for running a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am developing some scripts that I am planning to use in my LAB. Currently I installed Python and all the required modules only locally on the station that I am working with (the development station).

I would like to be able to run the scripts that i develop through each of my LAB stations.

What is the best practice to do that ?

Will I need to Install the same environment, except for the IDE of course, in all my stations ? If yes, then what is the recommended way to do that ?

By the way, is it mostly recommended to run those scripts from the command line screen (Windows) or is there any other elegant way to do that ?

Comment: These are scripts you just normally would run with the `python` command? How many computers will need this setup? What operating system?

Comment: And how would you imagine running them yourself? That info can be very helpful as we don't really know if your scripts are part of any framework or if they standalone scripts.

Comment: I have at least 3 more stations. All of them are Windows 7 or 10 stations. They are currently standalone, but I can already see how they will be part of the py.test framework

Comment: Lazy method: Just pull a git repo to all the computers. Slightly more fancy: Install `devpi` on one if the computers and use that as a package manager so you can install your software as a package on the other computers with `pip`.

Answer (score 4):

You should package up those scripts:

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And use one of the builtin methods of defining scripts within the package:

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html?highlight=scripts

This will help you maintain your scripts. You can version the package which is really useful because you will have bugs (we all write bugs) and you'll fix them in a newer version. Also, installing/upgrading a package is way easier than managing several independent scripts.

As for some "best practices" when writing the scripts, I recommend:

1) Write unit tests for your code: http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/tests/

2) Don't put any logic under your __name__ check. If anything, just wrap all that logic in a function named main, and call that under your __name__ check.

Bad

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
       foo = thing()
       args = get_args()
       try:
           blah()
       except DerpError:
           handle_derp()
```

Good

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Packaging my scripts will only require the station to have the Python installation. Right ?

Comment: No, you'll need to install Python on all the machines.
You can use the package to resolve any dependent modules you have in your scripts, and if those machines can reach the internet, they'll be downloaded and installed automatically: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html?highlight=requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a single script on multiple computers without installing Python everywhere you can "compile" the script to .exe using py2exe, cx_Freeze or PyInstall. The "compilation" actually packs Python and libraries into the generated .exe or accompanied files.

But if you plan to run many Python scripts you'd better install Python everywhere and distribute your scripts and libraries as Python packages (eggs or wheels).

Answer (score 0):

@moshe, if you have admin privileges on all these machines, I recommend installing the now-industry-standard [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distro of python. It comes with [Jupyter Notebook](http://jupyter.org/), an invaluable tool for scripting, saving, and sharing your code, as well as other handy things like visualizing your data.

Alternatively, you could simply fire up an [Amazon AWS free tier Linux](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) instance, setup Python the way you want it, then just use the shell on your lab machines to ssh into that instance. This might be the preferred way to go if you're using a shared machine where other people can install software and potentially wreck your environment setup.